# IntelliJ running basic android app = java.io.IOException: error=40

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

I have recently gone into android app development and I am using IntelliJ. I am trying to run the basic 'Hello World' app but I get an error:

> android-apt-compiler: Cannot run program "../android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/aapt": java.io.IOException: error=40, Too many levels of symbolic links

I have tried googling this error type and the error message but have not found anything that can help me fix this.

Any help would be appreciated at this point.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA 12.1.3 is not compatible with the most recent Android SDK tools update.

This problem is fixed in [IDEA 12.1.4](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+12.1+EAP) and [13 EAP](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+13+EAP).